# In Ruby, are val and val.nil? same?

Tags: ruby

As the title, are the following two statements same:

```
if val
```

and

```
if !val.nil?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > val = false
 => false 
2.0.0-p481 :002 > val.nil?
 => false
```

In ruby, `nil` and `false` are both falsey, but only `nil` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

No they both are different. Here is an example for you

```
irb(main):001:0> val = 10
=> 10
irb(main):002:0> if val
irb(main):003:1>   puts"kranthi"
irb(main):004:1> end
kranthi
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> val = nil
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> if val
irb(main):007:1>   puts"kranthi"
irb(main):008:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> val = "test"
=> "test"
irb(main):010:0> if val
irb(main):011:1>  puts "kranthi"
irb(main):012:1> end
kranthi
=> nil
```